# HQL error unexpected token: for max in spring

Tags: spring, hql

lets assume im having database with the details like :-

```
productid updateddate
1         24-03-2011 23:00:00
1         25-03-2011 23:00:00
2         25-03-2011 23:45:55
2         12-03-2011 23:45:22
```

i want to get details from database like:

```
productid updateddate
1         25-03-2011 23:00:00
2         25-03-2011 23:45:55
```

so i written query in hql like

```
from Summary  t    inner join(select productID,MAX(updatedDate) as Date from Regression 
group by productID)  x on x.productID = t.productID and x.Date = t.updatedDate;
```

when i have written in sql querybook it is not showing the desired output but when im writting it in hql it is saying error as:

at max word it is showing unexpected error.